Progress on the number of digits of Chaitin‘s constant
In „Computing a Glimpse of Randomness“ Calude et al compute the first 64 bits of Chaitin‘s constant; in fact they do better (prefix-free program length up to 84 bits), but need to restrict the result to 64 bits for avoiding a possible carry bit.
When superficially going over their paper, it would occur to me, that „simply“ throwing more compute ressources on the problem would give us (nowadays) substantially more bits (Calude et al published in 2002), but I don‘t see any progress here. Did I miss something?

You can golf a program whose halting depends on famous conjectures very easily, and this gives an upper bound to how much progress we can make.

That was Not exactly the question I have. I wanted to know whether using Calude‘s approach (generating programs in a prefix-free language and seeing of they halt using a java generator) would give us more digits when doing this on current hardware. I guess so, but didn‘t  find any references and this puzzles me.
